# Dojo - How to to position object relative to another object

Tags: dojo

Just like the title says. Because buildin widgets do not really fit, what I want to do, I need to make my own tooltipdialog implementation:

To start simple:

```
        dojo.query(".small-avatar").connect("onmouseenter", function () {
        var pos = dojo.position(this, true);
        dojo.query("#user-tooltip").style({ left: pos.x, top: pos.y, visibility:"visible" });
    });
```

I've come with this. Well I guess the problem is with pos. I've tried to digg with documentation, but honestly there is no word, on how access x and y position so I assumed it's with ".".

**UPDATE:**

After more checking, I figured out that problem lie in position it self, or style.
For some reason Dojo do not add coordinates to targeted node "#user-tooltip". It just change visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working:

```
 dojo.query(".small-avatar").connect("onmouseenter", function (e) {
        var pos = dojo.position(this, true);
        dojo.style(dojo.byId('user-tooltip'), { visibility: "visible", "left": pos.x+pos.w+'px', "top": pos.y+pos.h+'px' });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `pos.x` and `pos.y` correctly referenced since `dojo.position()` returns an object literal.  [From the Dojo docs](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/position), *The return object looks like:*

```
{ w: 300: h: 150, x: 700, y: 900, }
```

You may need to set `position: absolute` or `position: relative` on `#user-tooltip`.

Comment: I did. But actually problem lies elsewhere I've updated question.